# Comprensión de una instrucción booleana en C

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
boolean calcula_A(int x, Tabla t)
{
    int i;
    boolean b;
    i = x + 1;
    b = 0;
    while((b == 0) && (i != N))
    {
        b = b || t[x] == t[i];
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return b;
}
```

El problema está en que no entiendo el funcionamiento de la instrucción: `b = b || t[x] == t[i];`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor manera de comprender esto es meterlo en un if

```
if(b || t[x] == t[i]){

}
```

Si tu tienes el código de arriba, solo entrara a la condicion si `b = true` o si `t[x] == t[i]` es true. Como lo tienes tu esa variable `b` va a tomar el valor de la condicion, `true` o `false`. Si con los valores pasados a las variables entraria en la condicion, b
seria `true` sino `false`. Espero haberme explicado bien. Un saludo.

Comment: Entonces si no entiendo mal, si se cumple esa condición ¿haría la instrucción: i = i + 1?

Comment: Lo hará aunque no se cumpla, solo que la siguiente vuelta, se saldrá del While

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que ya lo he entendido bien.

Comment: No hay de que  ;)

Comment: Aun asi como nota, los tipos en C son bool no boolean. Y en el while deberías condicionarlo como while(b && i!=N) ya que b de por si es un booleano

Comment: El tipo boolean era un tipo que habia declarado porque no me dejan usar la libreria stdbool.h. Lo tengo declarado asi: typedef enum {FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1} boolean;. Pero gracias por la aportación

Answer (score 0):

Para entender esto, debes conocer la **precedencia** de los operadores, esto es, en qué orden se ejecutan las operaciones si no hay paréntesis especificando un orden. En tu caso, el operador de igualdad `==` tiene mayor precedencia que el operador OR lógico `||`. Entonces es como tener los siguientes paréntesis:

```
b = b || t[x] == t[i];

          |
          V

b = (b || (t[x] == t[i]));
```

Al final, el resultado se guarda en la variable `b`.